# i switched to Visual studio code and there is this one problem im facing

Tags: html, image, visual-studio-code

I was using brackets 'IDE' for web programming and everything worked just fine but now i have switched to Visual studio code and there is a problem i'm facing. The problem is that the images doesn't show up when i open the html file without the visual studio live server extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert all your images paths to relative paths by adding a dot in the beginning. For example /imgs/background => ./imgs/background

Comment: Thanks it works for the section images but not for header image any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try to change the path for your css and everything

Comment: Oky Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to redownload visual studio code and double check you have entered the correct file name and the file extension of the images because i use it without live server extension and there're no problems for me. :)